# mediaelement.js (wordpress 3.2.1 plugin) - video thumbnail appears blank when page loads

Tags: wordpress, plugins, mediaelement.js

I just installed this and it seems to work like a charm except for one thing.  When the page displays, the thumbnail is blank.  Is there a way I can use the first video frame as the thumbnail display or something like that?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

To have mediaelement.js load a thumbnail you need to ensure that preload is not set to none. For example:

```
<video src="myvideo.mp4" controls="controls" preload="metadata"></video>
```

Setting poster="poster.jpg" as per the example in the documentation won't necessarily work (unless you happen to have a file named poster.jpg). Though you can set the poster attribute to the location of an image to use as a thumbnail prior to loading the video, in the event you don't want the user agent to peek inside the media object.

See this answer for more information on the pre-load options - [What are the options for the mediaelement player's "preload" setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275206/what-are-the-options-for-the-mediaelement-players-preload-setting#20574160)

Comment: You can even use this in the shortcode `[mejsvideo preload="metadata"...]`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to put a poster="poster.jpg" attribute in the `<video>` tag.